# How to display tooltip with variable data?

Tags: html, tooltip

I have an form in `html` where I want to add the tooltip when the user hover on some input field. The tooltip data is however fetched from `json` and is dynamic. How do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
<div data-balloon="{{ obj.info }}" data-balloon-pos="up">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [id]="obj.key">
</div>
```

But it throws the template parse error:

```
Can't bind to 'balloon' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I also tried:

```
<div [data-balloon]="obj.info" data-balloon-pos="up">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [id]="obj.key">
</div>
```

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a pseudo-element with only CSS, to display any of your attribute:

```css
div[data-balloon] {
  float:left;
}

div[data-balloon]:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-balloon);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 4px; 
}
```

```html
<div data-balloon="My data here" data-balloon-pos="up">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [id]="obj.key">
</div>
```

If there is nothing more in your `div` element, it should work fine to use the `:hover` on the `div`.
If there is something more… You may want to move your `data-balloon` to your `input` element, as “parent” selection is not possible in CSS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Takit.. I am however looking to display tooltip data(variable data) when someone hover over the form input field.

Comment: @NamanArora Is there anything else in your `div` element ? If not, I updated my snippet and it should work fine. :)

Comment: No there isn't. Thanks @Takit.. Looks fine now.

Comment: Hi, I am falling to see how this answers the question. How do you change the string "My data here" with a variable {{obj.data}}. I get the same error.